# approach for array of arrays

Tags: c++

I'm doing this graphics project in which I have a set of points(in 3 coordinates)and have to transform them via matrix arithmetic.Each point needs to be transformed(rotation,scaling etc) and stored back.The obvious approach I figured was to use a 2-D array of size n by 3 matrix where every row would contain 3 values (x,y,z).Is there any better approach using vectors or structs?

Comment: Question is too vague without any piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors and structs:

```
struct Point 
{
   float x, y, z;
}

size_t n = 100;
size_t c = 3;
std::vector<Point> points;
points.resize(n * c);
//access
points[0].x = 0.1f;
//do want you want
```